# Python turtle unexpected screen margin

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have a screen set to 600x600 and a turtle that is 20x20 square. When I am trying to position the turtle using goto() to the top left corner it leaves a margin of about 10px as in the attached image.

The coordinates I am using are `tt.goto(-280, 280)`

What I find strange, is that on the right and bottom edges it works as expected. So when I set it to `tt.goto(280, -280)` then it goes exactly to the bottom right corner.

Where does this margin come from and what are the right coordinates to put it all the way to the edge?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with turtle inside Mac OS or your own machine, I have never faced that.